# How do I remove the default white Splash Screen in Flutter. I do not want a Splash Screen at all

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, splash-screen

There are many similar questions  on this site. But they do not answer what I want to accomplish. I do not even want a custom Splash Screen. I want to remove the Splash Screen completely or make it as short as possible.

Comment: The [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen#initializing-the-app) dont mention a way to reduce the time for default splash screen. i think the time taken by the default launch screen is the minimum time required for initialization.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the downvote. Its not in the docs that is why I posted it as a question. I will just let it be a white screen.

Comment: Didn't downvote. Up-voted. Create a [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues), flutter team might provide a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove the splashcreen as of now. All you can do is keep a solid color splashscreen.